# backlog items won't leave backlog once I've added them to a sprint (TFS)

Tags: tfs

I'm pretty new to managing sprint cycles in TFS, although I've used it before for development.  I have used JIRA for sprint planning/development in the past.

I have built out a product backlog and have about a dozen stories / items showing up under by 'backlog items.'  I've taken a few and moved them into our first sprint.. so now the iteration path shows as "product name"\release1\sprint1.  When I look at Sprint 1 I see only the stories and tasks that I've pulled into this sprint... just like I would expect.  BUT - I still see these same stories showing up in my backlog, even through the iteration path (hope I'm using that term correctly) shows as belonging in Sprint1.  I would expect that as you pull stories into a sprint, they leave the backlog.  I don't want to see stories that are being worked on in the current sprint in my backlog, as that will be confusing when we go to prioritize backlog items for the next sprint.

Did I mess something up?  Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mess it up. The functionality to optionaly filter those items from the backlog is part of Update 3 of TFS 2013 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/07/02/vs-tfs-2013-3-update-3-rc.aspx). Till that time they are/stay visible.